# How to pass multiple parameters of unknown length from react to django url

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have to pass multiple parameters to a Django view through Django URL.I am passing the values from React fetch.The list of parameters is variable.For example,it could be 2 sometimes and 3 or 4 sometimes. I have following urls.py file

```
path('getallvalues/<pk>',views.MultipleValueView.as_view())
```

views.py

```
class MultipleValueView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer_class=ValueSerializer
        listofvalues=["test","test2"]
        return Response({"weights":getMultipleValueJourney(listofvalues)[0],"years":getMultipleValueJourney(listofvalues)[1]})
```

React code:

```
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/getallvalues/"+valueList)
        .then(response =>  response.json())
        .then(json => {
            var {years,weights}=this.state;
            this.setState({
              
              weights:json.weights,
              years:json.years,
              
              }}
```

How could I structure my urls.py file?I have seen certain answers from stackoverflow but none of them worked in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

add query parameters to your fetch call at frontend then at backend, you can get those params and filter based on them like

```
qp= self.request.GET.get('param_name')
if qp is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(some_condition)
```

In this way, you wouldn't need to add any params in your Django URLs or you can checkout Django filters package if you need something more which is mentioned in DRF's docs as well https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @MohammedFaisal  My question is how to add these parameters in url because the number of parameters are changing all the time

Comment: @Sam you can pass any number of parameters as queries via fetch from the frontend there is no limit it can be 1 2 3 or n. You can then check if the parameter is passed in the view with the above code and then do whatever you want with it. Why do you specifically want to keep the params in django URL?

Comment: so I can leave my url as it is?

Comment: yes, you can. I said the same in my answer too :P. Hope this helps

Comment: Great!One last question.what do you mean by param_name in view? @MohammadFaisal

Comment: its the name of the parameter you pass from frontend like if you fetch with URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getallvalues?param1=something&param2=something". Then the param names would param1 and param2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224737/discussion-between-sam-and-mohammad-faisal).